# Error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kernel'

Tags: javascript, python, camera, google-colaboratory

There is this javascript code to run your local system camera on colab, that .ipynb file works fine on colab and camera opens but when i try to convert it into a .py and run it on my local system this error pops up, i have other google-colab lib installed in my system.

js code used to run camera:

```py
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
from google.colab.output import eval_js
from base64 import b64decode

def take_photo(filename='photo.jpg', quality=0.8):
  js = Javascript('''
    async function takePhoto(quality) {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      const capture = document.createElement('button');
      capture.textContent = 'Capture';
      div.appendChild(capture);

      const video = document.createElement('video');
      video.style.display = 'block';
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});

      document.body.appendChild(div);
      div.appendChild(video);
      video.srcObject = stream;
      await video.play();

      // Resize the output to fit the video element.
      google.colab.output.setIframeHeight(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, true);

      // Wait for Capture to be clicked.
      await new Promise((resolve) => capture.onclick = resolve);

      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
      canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
      stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
      div.remove();
      return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality);
    }
    ''')
  display(js)
  data = eval_js('takePhoto({})'.format(quality))
  binary = b64decode(data.split(',')[1])
  with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(binary)
  return filename
```

[link to the js code](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=SucxddsPhOmj)

Error messsage:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "repnet_task2.py", line 969, in <module>
    record_video(INTERVAL_IN_MS, int(RECORDING_TIME_IN_SECONDS*1000/INTERVAL_IN_MS)) 
  File "repnet_task2.py", line 752, in record_video
    eval_js('recordVideo({},{},{})'.format(interval_in_ms, num_frames, quality))
  File "/home/hp/Downloads/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/colab/output/_js.py", line 35, in eval_js
    kernel = _ipython.get_kernel()
  File "/home/hp/Downloads/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/colab/_ipython.py", line 28, in get_kernel
    return get_ipython().kernel
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kernel'
```

Comment: thank you @James Z for the edit